# NullPointerException when try change text in textView from other class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Can u help me understand why when I want set text in `TextView`, I got `NullPointerException`? I know, because my `TextView` is null but how I can get `TextView` again?

What is my logic:

1. Start Application
2. Click button
3. Go to `nullPoint` and get data from firebase, when the proccessing is finished back to `MainActivity` and update text in `TextView`.

This is my example code:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnAddNewWord = findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnAddNewWord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                nullPoint np = new nullPoint();
                np.takeCount();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setTextView(int count){
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText("count = " + count);
    }
}
```

**nullPoint**

```
public class nullPoint {

    //the class gets asynchronous data from the Firebase database and does not know when the process will end
    public void takeCount(){

        //det data
        //.
        //.
        // finish

        //send data to MainActivity and update textView text
        MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
        ma.setTextView(5);
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is `nullPoint` class is defined inside your `MainActivity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the `nullPoint` class is not inside the `MainActivity`. As a result, inside your `nullPoint` class there is no reference for the `TextView` in which you are trying to set a data.

In your case I would like to suggest you to implement a listener like the following.

```
public interface FirebaseResponseListener {
    void onFirebaseResponseReceived(int count); 
}
```

Now from your `MainActivity`, you need to implement the listener as follows.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FirebaseResponseListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnAddNewWord = findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnAddNewWord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                nullPoint np = new nullPoint();
                np.listener = this; // Initialize the listener here
                np.takeCount();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setTextView(int count){
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText("count = " + count);
    }

    @Override
    void onFirebaseResponseReceived(int count) {
        setTextView(count);
    }
}
```

And you have to add a listener in your `nullPoint` class as well.

```
public class nullPoint {
    public FirebaseResponseListener listener; 

    //the class gets asynchronous data from the Firebase database and does not know when the process will end
    public void takeCount(){

        //det data
        //.
        //.
        // finish

        //send data to MainActivity and update textView text
        listener.onFirebaseResponseReceived(5);
    }
}
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thank You Reaz Murshed, yes You solved my problem :)